# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Read the other questions similar to this but none fixed my problem. I get the error in the title when I try to run the simulator, and this warning message:

`directory not found for option '-F/Users/Grady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nomadik-himgaykkfxgfvhfcmtazniqkaxwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac`

```
/Users/Grady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nomadik-himgaykkfxgfvhfcmtazniqkaxwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Nomadik.app/Nomadik normal x86_64
cd /Users/Grady/Documents/SE498_Projects/Nomadik
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/Grady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nomadik-himgaykkfxgfvhfcmtazniqkaxwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Grady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nomadik-himgaykkfxgfvhfcmtazniqkaxwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Grady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nomadik-himgaykkfxgfvhfcmtazniqkaxwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac -F/Users/Grady/Documents/SE498_Projects/Nomadik/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/Grady/Documents/SE498_Projects/Nomadik/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/Grady/Documents/SE498_Projects/Nomadik/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/Grady/Documents/SE498_Projects/Nomadik/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/Grady/Documents/SE498_Projects/Nomadik/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -filelist /Users/Grady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nomadik-himgaykkfxgfvhfcmtazniqkaxwi/Build/Intermediates/Nomadik.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Nomadik.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Nomadik.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.3 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Grady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nomadik-himgaykkfxgfvhfcmtazniqkaxwi/Build/Intermediates/Nomadik.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Nomadik.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Nomadik.swiftmodule -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Grady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nomadik-himgaykkfxgfvhfcmtazniqkaxwi/Build/Intermediates/Nomadik.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Nomadik.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Nomadik_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Grady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nomadik-himgaykkfxgfvhfcmtazniqkaxwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Nomadik.app/Nomadik
```

I'd really appreciate it someone could help me out here..

Comment: Did you try a clean and rebuild?  If that didn't work, did you try deleting DerivedData?

Comment: if NonodyNada's advice didn't work, Try closing xcode and reopening it again.

Comment: Neither of those worked, I'm gonna try removing CocoaPods

Comment: Pls can you share code of podfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Clean & rebuild the project after that ...

Go to your build settings and switch the target's settings to ENABLE_BITCODE = YES for now.